# ld: library not found for -lsp

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am converting objective-c project to swift.

Staring with the AppDelegate file with steps [here](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/converting-an-objective-c-app-to-swift/118):

1. create new AppDelegate.swift file and fill it with the following:`

   ```
   import UIKit
   @UIApplicationMain
   class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

     var window: UIWindow?

   func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:[NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool 
   {
     return true
   }

     // some other delegate methods...
   }
   ```
2. delete `main.m` file (I'm keeping `AppDelegate.m/.h` for comparison)
3. run project and get error:

> Ld
>   /Users/bluewhere/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-abomtwmgtbxskyglyerdeblzvtrh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/MyApp
>   normal x86_64
>
> // ... chunk of error message...
>
> ld: library not found for -lsp
>
> clang: error: linker command failed
>   with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

This project is ready for sale, which means creating a new project is not an option.

Any Advice?

Comment: So, which library is it supposed to be, and does it exist anywhere in your project space?

Comment: @Avi not sure which lib Xcode is complaining about. Should I show the entire error message?